# The process cannot access the file 'myfile.jpg' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

Hello guys I have made a method that checks if an image exists (overwrite it) or not (create it), but when I execute

```
System.IO.File.Delete(wmImg);
```

the system raise the error:

> The process cannot access the file 'myfile.jpg' because it is being
>   used by another process

Below the code:

```
wmImg = Server.MapPath("myFileNew.jpg");
wroi = Server.MapPath("myFile.jpg");

string s11 = op.ToString();
float ss = float.Parse(s11);
float opacityvalue = ss / 10;

var img = ImageUtils.ImageTransparency.ChangeOpacity(Image.FromFile(wroi), opacityvalue);

if (System.IO.File.Exists(wmImg))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(wmImg); // Raise the error ...
    img.Save(wmImg);
}
else
{
    img.Save(wmImg);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you made a method. Is there a question or a problem?

Comment: yes there is a problem: The process cannot access the file 'myfile.jpg' because it is being used by another process

Comment: Then another process has a lock on the file. Try to find which process uses it.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Image.FromFile` which returns an `IDisposable`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx) specifies:

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

So you have to put `Image.FromFile` in a `using` block

Answer (score 0):

This checks if wmImg exists, if not it will throw an exception and perform the catch. Now your application won't block by Image.FromFile like Wimmel explained.

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(wmImg, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete(wmImg);
        img.Save(wmImg);
    }
    catch
    {
         //You could catch some more error here, but for now.
         img.Save(wmImg);
    }
}
```